# How do I make an element open a specific file path in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directory

In Visual Studio, I am trying to create an application that will lead users to a specific file path. The directory I am trying to make it open in is as follows.

```
C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds
```

Unfortunately I am only able to get it to start in the `...\oobe` directory when using the following code, otherwise it starts in the "My Documents" directory.

```
Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", "C:\Windows\System32\oobe")
End Sub
```

I am aware that \info\background is not normally in the system but will be created by the program if not already by the user. What seems to be the problem is that Windows does not register the folders. Is there different code that I need to use to open in the correct directory? I am writing in .VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below links are solution for your question 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53489/Customisation-with-VB-Changing-Logon-Backgrounds-i 
http://www.morrisonrenfroe.netdcon.net/vb/apps/bgchanger/vbcode.txt

Comment: It took me a while but I eventually was able to fix a few errors that came up when I tried building from the links you provided... Thank you.